# Clear app data and cache on FORCE_INSTALLED apps when kioskCustomLauncherEnabled is on

Tags: android-management-api

We have a few private apps we distribute to dedicated Android devices, when we move them between users I want to be able to clear the app data from the apps. A few months ago, this was working but recently when we go to clear app data (from Settings) it isn't allowed by the policy.
We don't want users to be able to uninstall the apps but we do want to be able to clear app data so it doesn't retain user data from the prior user.

1. Is there a way to just clear a single apps data?
2. Is there some policy setting which controls whether or not you can clear app data?

Our current workaround is to manually switch to a profile without the apps (the ones we want to clear) then switch them back to the pertinent profile which forces and uninstall then reinstall of the apps. However, this is more cumbersome than we would like.

Comment: Per the November 2020 release notes for Android Management API:
Starting in Android 11, users can no longer clear app data or force stop applications when the device is configured as a kiosk (that is, when the InstallType of one application in ApplicationPolicy is set to KIOSK).

However - in my scenario I don't have any applications set to KIOSK but I do have the kioskCustomLauncherEnabled. Either they are limiting more than what the release notes state or the Kiosk Custom Launcher is secretly a KIOSK mode app that triggers this condition

Answer (score -1):

I think this is working as intended. +1 on `kioskCustomerLauncher` however being an app running in kiosk mode isn't a "secret", it's just transparent to the policy for ease-of-use, in my opinion :)

TheoL

AndroidEnterprise

Comment: Is there any way to clear app data for a single app then? The current behavior is not good for our workflow.


Otherwise, my workaround works but it's pretty tedious to switch profiles to delete the apps and then switch back to reload the apps. Our profiles have 1-3 apps that are used with a given user for a while, then we wipe off user data and give to someone else. Would be nice to let my operations folk just clear the app data from their side without involving any phone provisioning help.